# railsで、modelにforeign_keyを指定した場合のorderはどう書けばいいのでしょうか。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql, rails-activerecord

railsで、modelにforeign_keyを指定した場合に、orderメソッドを使ってソートしたいです。

下記のようにユーザーと部署テーブルがあり、
ユーザーは部署に2つ所属する場合、

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :unit_first,  foreign_key: 'unit_first_id',  class_name: 'Unit'
  belongs_to :unit_second, foreign_key: 'unit_second_id', class_name: 'Unit'
end

class Unit < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :first_user,  foreign_key: 'unit_first_id',  class_name: 'User'
  has_many :second_user, foreign_key: 'unit_second_id', class_name: 'User'
end
```

一つの部署に所属するのであればこんな感じだと思いますが、

```
User.joins(:unit).order("`units`.`name` ASC")
```

指定の仕方がわかりません。。
教えてください！

追記:

複数ソートを実装したくて下記で動きましたが、
arelでもいいのでSQLを直書きしない方法はありますか？

```
users = User
    .joins!("INNER JOIN `units` AS `unit_first` ON `unit_first`.`id` = `users`.`unit_first_id`")
    .joins!("INNER JOIN `units` AS `unit_second` ON `unit_second`.`id` = `users`.`unit_second_id`")
    .order!("`unit_first`.`name` ASC, `unit_second`.`name` ASC")
```

追記2:

回答を参考にSQLを見てやってみて、下記で動作します

```
User.joins(:unit_first, :unit_second).order("users.name ASC", "unit_seconds_users.name ASC")
```

先にmodelでbelongs_toを定義したカラムは通常通りのテーブル名で
後にmodelでbelongs_toを定義したカラムは

```
#{複数系カラム名}_#{テーブル名}
```

という形でエイリアスになっていました。

ただ、unit_second単体でソートする場合も一度unit_firstをjoinさせる必要があるので注意が必要っぽいです。

```
User.joins(:unit_first, :unit_second).order("unit_seconds_users.name ASC")
```

うーん。

Comment: 質問があります。
最終的にほしい情報は「所属部署名順のユーザー一覧」との認識で良いのでしょうか？
また、問題の要因の一つにテーブル設計があるように感じます。「ユーザーは部署に2つ所属する」とあることからUserとUnitは多対多の関係であるのに中間テーブルを利用しない設計にしているのはどのような理由があるのでしょうか？

Comment: 1syoさん、
所属部署名順のユーザー一覧の認識で間違いありません。
たしかにちょっとおかしい設計ですが、実際実装したコードではなくて、説明しやすいようにこういうサンプルを用意しました。実際は、会社に所属する経理担当者と現場担当者、何々担当者などというカラムがあります。多対多の設計だとどの担当かわからないのでこういう設計になってます。
一対多のこういう場面はどう書けば良いか迷っています。

Comment: araさん。回答ありがとうございます。あくまでUserはunit_first_id、unit_second_idを持つものとのことで承知しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下のように書くのはどうでしょうか？

```
User.joins(:unit_first, :unit_second).order("users.name", "users_unit_second.name")
```

"users.name"や"users_unit_second.name"の部分は、発行されるSQLにあわせて変更する必要があるかもしれません。

#### 追記

> ただ、unit_second単体でソートする場合も一度unit_firstをjoinさせる必要があるので注意が必要っぽいです。 User.joins(:unit_first, :unit_second).order("unit_seconds_users.name ASC")

その場合はこうすれば良い気がします。

```
User.joins(:unit_second).order("units.name ASC")
```

いかがでしょうか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
実際にSQLをみてやってみた結果下記で動作しました。

    User.joins(:unit_first, :unit_second).order("users.name ASC", "unit_seconds_users.name ASC")

先にmodelでbelongs_toを定義したカラムは通常通りのテーブル名で
後にmodelでbelongs_toを定義したカラムは

    #{複数系カラム名}_#{テーブル名}

という形でエイリアスになっていました。

ただ、unit_second単体でソートする場合も一度unit_firstをjoinさせる必要があるので注意が必要っぽいです。
    User.joins(:unit_first, :unit_second).order("unit_seconds_users.name ASC")

Comment: 追記ありがとうございます！
私もそれでorderかけれると幸せだったんですが、
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'unit_seconds_users.id' in 'field list'
とエラーで怒られてしまいます。
unitテーブルをロードしてないから？でしょうか。unit_firstを先にjoinsするといけました

Comment: なるほど。。。手元にある似たような構成のRailsプロジェクトだと、1個でもいけたんですけどね。ちなみにそのプロジェクトはRails 4.1.12でPostgreSQLでした。もしかするとバージョン等によって動きが変わることがあるのかもしれません。（全く未検証ですが）